# Key Value pairs parsing with optional quotes

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse key value pairs out of a string in PHP.
Space separator, quoted/unquoted surrounded by spaces
This is my attempt.

`preg_match_all("/(\w+)[\s]*=[\s]*(([^'\s]+)|'([^']*)')/", $text, $matches);`

The problem with this is that it fills two different arrays with ([^'\s]+) and '([^']*)'

A further improvement would also be allowing for double quotes but any of my attempts has failed.

Comment: It would be better if the input and expected output examples are laid out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using non-capturing groups can help. It can be done as a small modification in your original regex-

```
(\w+)[\s]*=[\s]*((?:[^'\s]+)|'(?:[^']*)')
                  ^^           ^^
```

This makes either value types to be captured in the same group.
Demo [Here](http://regex101.com/r/lP4nH1)

**EDIT -**
As a further modification, if you want to allow double quotes in your values, then try this -

```
(\w+)[\s]*=[\s]*((?:[^"'\s]+)|'(?:[^']*)'|"(?:[^"]*)")
```

Demo [Here](http://regex101.com/r/kC0kU1)

Answer (score -2):

You can use a simpler regex:

```
(.*)=(.*)
```

Group 1 contains the key, while Group 2 contains the value.